# How to convert multi-line String to array of line keeping indentation

Tags: java, angular

C or C++ code in String variable. I want to convert that multi line  String variable into List of String, but i want to preserve the indentation to display the code in my angular application. 
This is what i am doing

```
String diffContent = "multi line Java c or c++ code";
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(new StringReader(diffContent));
```

But i am loosing indentation by this. Is there any possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the lines on the basis of "\n" :

```
String splitLines[] = diffContent.split("\n");
```

Then display each String in new line.

Comment: This won't loose the indentation ?

Comment: Each String will contain all the characters, spaces and tabs in that line.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   String diffContent = "multi line Java c or c++ code";
    String str[] = diffContent.split(" ");
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al = Arrays.asList(str);
        for(String s: al){
           System.out.println(s);
        }
       }

}
```

Comment: public class HelloWorld
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello World!");
 }
}

Let say this is variable diffContent

Comment: Can u be more specific?

Comment: I am having Java or c code. I need to display that in UI with out loosing indentation. I need to convert it into lines of string to do some manipulation at UI